# GAE - Issue with GET

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to make a very basic sign up form on Google App Engine that redirects and writes 'Welcome, (name_of_user)' when all input is valid. It seems I'm having a problem with the last GET function. The redirect page shows only 'Welcome, '. Any help with this code would be really appreciated. Thank you. http://pastebin.com/jTSRXkpb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a few minutes and learn how to put code in your posts so that it'll be part of the permanent record of your question.

In `WelcomeHandler`,

```
user = self.request.get('username')
```

has no query parameter named `username`, since `self.redirect("/welcome")` isn't passing one. Try

```
self.redirect("/welcome?username=something")
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I'm super new to this. Could 'something' just be a random word or should it be a more specific syntax from my code? I tried using just any word and it didn't work..

Comment: Any random word. The point is that it's passed as a 'query parameter' to your welcome handler. Then `self.request('username')` should give you the string "something". If you're new to HTTP, that's the tricky bit. The rest is standard Python.

Comment: I don't want self.request.get('username') to return any random word. I want it to return the username string that the user submitted in the Signup form. When I try:

 self.redirect("/welcome?username=username") 
, I get the literal string 'username' instead.

Comment: Once you understand the basic plumbing, it's an easy step to turn that into `self.redirect("/welcome?username=" + name)`, which advances the problem to one of putting putting a string representing a user name into `name`.